# project not using .npmrc file

Tags: javascript, npm, npmrc

I have `.npmrc` file at the root in my project. But for some reason `npm i` doesn't use that for proxy. Instead it is picking up my `bash_profile`. Can someone please help how to force use `.npmrc` file?

Comment: It should be using it. What does `npm config list` output?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Looks like I had 2 different `.npmrc` at different locations. I deleted one and kept the one in my root project. I think that was the issue